# How to store data in text format and then search via it?

Tags: knowledge-organization

I have a system of storing data that just came up. It wasn't planned, it was just comfortable for me. I am trying to improve that system. I am sure something like that is around, but not sure how to look for it.

Basically what I do is I record nouns to start with '@' while verbs start with '#'.

Like some examples:

- @Toyota #car_service #oil_change done for 5000km at $50. Next at
  160,000km. 20200927
- @Toyota #car_service #brake_pad #rear_right #rear_left at $100.
  20200927
- #rent @Downtown #2bedroom $3000
- #paid @Jack $500 for @office. 20200927

I store data like this in a simple .txt file and search via it later. I would like to bring a structure like group '#oil_change' & '#brake_pad' as a child of '#car_service. recognise date in 'yyyymmdd' and group based on date. When I search, I would like to see the output instead of searching through the file by clicking next.

I currently do it via my laptop and would love to get something that can run on the mobile.

The '#rent' is info I just got via talking to someone and I stored in case I need in the future.

While I paid petty cash of the company to Jack that I just kept in my personal record. I don't do it often, just stored it in case needed. While I did fill the form for it in the company.

I am not sure if there is any name for the kind of data entry I am doing.

Any info/feedback would be great.

I am looking for an app that works in ios or android.

Comment: As this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. – I assume you're looking for a software or library. Could you please **[edit]** your question and specify which of the two – plus if it's a library, for what programming language; if it's a programm, what OS it should run on?

Comment: I am looking for a software that will do what I am trying to do. I just explained what I am expecting the software to do.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find any prewritten software to process your unusual and fairly odd data format. Also, I don't see any "@" symbols in your examples. If you are willing to reformat your data into a standard format, I recommend you consider JSON.

Comment: Actually I typed in '@' but it got replaced with 'u/'. I just noticed it. I have corrected it now.
JSON is the data storage format I prefer. I am looking for a software that will do what I want.

Comment: Can you code, or are you willing to learn?